# How to correctly type an 'omit' function in TypeScript to avoid error messages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typeorm

```
export const omit = <T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: U[]): Exclude<T, U> =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce(  
    (acc: any, curr: any) => (keys.includes(curr) ? acc : { ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] }),
    {}
  );
```

Getting an error message stating `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.`

And would like to have no error messages and a correctly typed function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to return an object so I believe you want to return `Omit<T, U>` and not `Exclude<T, U>` :

You can see the difference [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk)

Here is how you can avoid your errors :

```
export const omit = <T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: U[]): Omit<T, U> =>
  (Object.keys(obj) as U[]).reduce(
    (acc, curr) => (keys.includes(curr) ? acc : { ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] }),
    {} as Omit<T, U>
  );
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. One thing that might be good to change is your 'includes' typo so that others don't think that this doesn't work when in fact it works great!

Comment: In addition to this, how would I type this 'pluck' function better to get better error messages?
`export const pluck = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> =>
  keys.reduce((acc: any, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] }), {});`

Comment: Thanks for the typo ! I just fixed it. Let me see for the pluck.

Comment: Here is your pluck function :
`export const pluck = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> =>
  keys.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] }), {} as Pick<T, K>);`

but I am not quite sure of what you want...